# Finding scalar multiples of two variable Vector sum

Tags: vectors

If a=3i+2j,b=3j-2i and c=12i-5j,find numbers p and q such that pa+qb=c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the system $$3p-2q=12$$ and $$2p+3q=-5$$

Comment: I got to this part of the question, however this question was from my math textbook. The given answers for this question are p=5, q=7. If what you're saying is correct then I was right and the book was wrong? That's a relief! Thanks.